# Need help prompting strings and adding them to one

Tags: python, string

The assignment is to take two strings, both listed below, and to scan `str_NamesIDs` for their dietary letter, such as M, V, or A. If one of those letters is in the string "food", we must store only the word it stands for to that persons name, and print the persons name "can eat" m + v, etc.

What I'm trying to do is generalize the input of the names and the diet foods. So for the diet legend, I'm asking for the user to input 'A:Alcohol' and add that to the current string "food". If the user inputs 'stop', it want it to break and move on.

```html
str_NamesIDs = 'John MVA, Henry MVN,...'
food = 'V:Vegatarian,M:Meat,A:Alcohol,N:Non-Alcoholic'

#Ask for dietary legend
food = ' ';

while food.upper() != 'STOP':
    food = food + (raw_input('Enter Diet list in Format Letter:Catagory '));
```

Comment: What should this do, and in what way is it deficient?  Or, put another way: what is the question?

Comment: Seriously? The code snippet option is for **HTML**, **CSS** and **JavaScript**, not for **Python**.

Comment: If `food` begins life as `' '`, and then you add stuff to it, when is it ever going to be equal to `'STOP'`?

Comment: @PaulGriffiths That's what I'm having a hard time figuring out. I want it to prompt the user to keep adding food, and stopping when food equals to stop. So, I'm looping while food does not equal stop, right?

Comment: @HarrisNghiem: Well, obviously you need to read your input into a separate variable, otherwise you'll never be able to compare it to `'STOP'`. If it doesn't equal `'STOP'`, then and only then should you concatenate it to `food`. If you need to compare your input to what you store in `food` in your second line, then obviously you'll need a third variable, otherwise you'll overwrite that original data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your input in a separate variable. If you add your input to the same string, it'll never equal `'STOP'`, so your loop will never end. You have to be able to compare only what was last input, rather than the concatenation of everything that's been historically input.

This code will do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

words = ''

while True:

    # Get input

    new_word = raw_input('Enter a word: ')

    # Stop loop if user entered 'stop'

    if new_word.upper() == 'STOP':
        break

    # Add comma to string if this is not the first word

    if words:
        words += ','

    # Add word to string

    words += new_word

print "Your words are: " + words
```

with output:

```
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$ ./words.py
Enter a word: Something
Enter a word: wicked
Enter a word: this
Enter a word: way
Enter a word: comes
Enter a word: stop
Your words are: Something,wicked,this,way,comes
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$
```

Comment: This was perfect, thank you. I never thought of using a bool with 'with'. Also, adding the coma after the first word was awesome. This was exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I understand now why I couldn't just have one variable, 'food'.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accepting the answer if it's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
str_NamesIDs = 'John MVA, Henry MVN'
checking_list = [i.strip().split()[-1] for i in str_NamesIDs.split(',')]
food = []
input_string = ''
while input_string.upper() != 'STOP':
    input_string = raw_input('Enter Diet list in Format Letter:Catagory ');
    # simply checking without using regex
    if input_string[0].isupper() and input_string[0] == input_string[2] and input_string[1]==':' and any(input_string[2] in i for i in checking_list):
        food.append(input_string[2:])
print food
```

Comment: this is really simple and not handling repetitive problem.

Answer (score -1):

This is not the best way to store data, it's better to use one of the two representations.
- Dictionaries:

```
food = {V:Vegatarian,M:Meat,A:Alcohol,N:Non-Alcoholic}
```

- List of tuples:

  food = [(V,Vegatarian),(M,Meat),(A,Alcohol),(N,Non-Alcoholic)]
- Here is a snippet to help you understand the problem (You should test and add more scenarios).

Ask the user to enter data, you should store the data entered in a variable

> ```
> food = {"V":"Vegatarian","M":"Meat","A":"Alcohol","N":"Non-Alcoholic"}
>  str_NamesID=raw_input('Enter your name')
>  food = ' ';
>  CatagoryList=[]
>  Catagory= ''
>  while Catagory.upper() != 'STOP':
>      Catagory= raw_input('Enter Diet list in Format Letter:Catagory ')
>      CatagoryList+=[Catagory]
>      if Catagory not in CatagoryList:
>          food += "+"+food[Catagory]
>  #print food
>  if not food[:-1]:
>      print str_NamesID, "can eat nothing"
>  else:
>      print str_NamesID, "can eat",food[:-1]
> ```

Let me explain to you.

- First thing is: 
  You can't search in food using letter, it's ambiguous. 
  imagine if you are storing "Vegetarian" first time, then you enter "N", how can you verify that "N" that you are looking for is referring to "Non-Alcoholic" and not for in the vegetarian (last letter is n).

What you should do is storing Keys (V,M,A,N) in different list (to check), and store the words in different phrase (food) to print it later.

- Second thing:
  use dictionaries. V is a key, and Vegatarian is a value 
  V[Key]:Vegatarian[Value]
- I use food[:-1] to delete the last charachter (because I add + operator when I concatinate foods everytime, you can print food in the middle to verify)
- if food is empty, you should print something meaningful, so I added another condition to print "nothing " in this case

Comment: Whoever gave -1: Can you explain why !

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working the way I'd like it to. It's not scanning the letters in str_NamesID to see if it's on the CatagoryLisa.

Comment: It's doing that automatically for food[Catagory](this means that it's searching for a value where the key if Category). Did you study Dictionaries ?

Comment: str_NamesIDs are names(people), they are different than the food names (food).